# My program is about guessing a number between 0 and 100 in python

Tags: python-3.x

```
print("Please think of a number between 0 and 100!")
low = 0
high = 100
ans = (low + high) / 2
while True:
    print("Is your secret number %d " %ans)
    userguess = input("Enter 'h' to indicate the guess is too high. Enter 
    'l' to indicate the guess is too low. Enter 'c' to indicate I guessed 
    correctly. ")
    if userguess == 'h':
        high = ans
    elif userguess == 'l':
        low = ans
    elif userguess == 'c':
        break
    else :
        print("Sorry, I did not understand your input.")
        continue
    ans = (low + high) / 2

print("Game over. Your secret number was: %d" %ans)
```

When The number is 42 and 91 it doesn't work the way it should be . What is wrong in this code .

Comment: What exactly doesn’t work? How is it wrong?

Comment: Use `//` for integer division instead of `/`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get intermediate floating point values when you should be using integer arithmetic only

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question, nothing is wrong in the code. Already try with the numbers you mention, and it is working correctly.

According to the Python 3.x documentation, you are using the printf style function correctly. The only not optional component for this type of conversion is

> 1. The ´%´ character, which marks the start of the specifier.

So, you are forcing the conversion from float to "Signed integer decimal" to print it correctly to the user.

Everything is correct and in my end, everything works fine.

Comment: So i was doing a computer science course on edx and this was the issue, it was running perfectly but the only problem was using integer conversion